# Dynamics - Creating a Task using API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, office365api, dynamics-crm-365

```
    {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://cmpanydynamicsurl.com/api/data/v8.2/tasks', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, 
     Headers:
      {
        OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
        OData-Version: 4.0
        Accept: application/json
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Content-Length: 162
      }}
```

Using the above request, I am trying to create a task against an account using Dynamics API post action.

Json Model being sent -

```
 {
    "subject":"NEW TEST TASK FOR ACCOUNT",
    "_regardingobjectid_value@odata.bind":"/accounts(08b582ad-4e2f-e711-8101-5065f38a4a21)"
 }
```

I am receiving this error message and have had no luck with searching the internet?

> A property '_regardingobjectid_value' which only has property
>   annotations in the payload but no property value is declared to be of
>   type 'Edm.Guid'. In OData, only navigation properties and named
>   streams can be represented as properties without values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct payload is

```
{
    "subject": "NEW TEST TASK FOR ACCOUNT",
    "regardingobjectid_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(08b582ad-4e2f-e711-8101-5065f38a4a21)"
}
```

You have to tell somehow to which object type you are binding, because regardingobjectid has mutliple types, and every type has its own separate relationship (in this case regardingobjectid_account). You are trying to bind value to a plain "Guid" property (because "_regardingobjectid_value" is a "Guid") but such property should be assigned exactly the same as you are doing with subject, so simply `"_regardingobjectid_value": "08b582ad-4e2f-e711-8101-5065f38a4a21"` but this will not work as you did not provide the type of entity.

Comment: Perfect thankyou :) I was assuming that the value /accounts(guid) was enough to know the type.